# Select related data from same table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'products'

```
id | title | color_id (fk) | type_id (fk) | price_range_id (fk)
```

I perform a select query:

```
SELECT * FROM products where id = 1
```

I need to get related products from the same table. How would I go about doing this? So I need to select the row with id 1 then select 10 other products that have the same `colour_id`, `type_id` and `price_range_id`.

Also, if 10 related products are not selected, I need to select the remainder at random, but this must not include the rows already selected.

I'm not expecting someone on here to do all the work, just could some one point me in the right direction where to start with this problem?

Comment: `self join` on the various fields, which will quickly get ugly.

Comment: You forgot to tell us: Which database you use. If stored procedures are an option. Which method do you use to access the database? Client, JDBC, Perl, Python, PHP ????? Can you execute SQL in multiple rounds or are you bound to one big SQL statement? If you use a programming language, it is not a big deal. If it must be one statement, I see no simple solution.

Comment: Using PHP & MYSQL and any solution, not bound to one statement

Answer (score 0):

Hi if I understand your question correctly you should create stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_select(IN inId INT)
BEGIN
  SET @numSelected := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1
  WHERE color_id = (SELECT color_id FROM t1 WHERE id = inId)
  AND type_id = (SELECT type_id FROM t1 WHERE id = inId) 
  AND price_range_id = (SELECT price_range_id FROM t1 WHERE id = inId)
  AND id != inId
  LIMIT 10);

  SET @numRemaind := (10 - @numSelected);

  PREPARE statement FROM 'SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id = ?
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t1
  WHERE color_id = (SELECT color_id FROM t1 WHERE id = ?)
  AND type_id = (SELECT type_id FROM t1 WHERE id = ?) 
  AND price_range_id = (SELECT price_range_id FROM t1 WHERE id = ?)
  AND id != ?
  LIMIT 10) t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t1
  WHERE id != ? AND 
  id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM t1
             WHERE color_id = (SELECT color_id FROM t1 WHERE id = ?)
             AND type_id = (SELECT type_id FROM t1 WHERE id = ?) 
             AND price_range_id = (SELECT price_range_id FROM t1 WHERE id = ?)
             AND id != ?)
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT ?) tx';

  SET @p1 = inId;
  SET @p2 = @numRemaind;

  EXECUTE statement USING @p1, @p1, @p1, @p1, @p1, @p1, @p1, @p1, @p1, @p1, @p2;

END//
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b280/2) for that to see how it's work. In the first row of the table there will be selected rows with the same color_id, type_id and price_range id, and if there are not 10 rows to add it will add random rows which are not selected in previous steps...

GL!